# Upload a system.drawing.image to my website

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, file-upload, upload

This should be fairly simple, but I just can't see the logic in it! In my C# code I'm having an image object (System.Drawing.Image) which I want to upload to my website.

I know how to upload files with the FileUpload control, but what about when I only have the Image object?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have an `Image`, simply turn it into a byte array and send it to a service. Here's [my article](http://nesteruk.org/blog/post/Sending-a-Bitmap-to-a-web-service.aspx) on the subject.

Comment: I believe your link is broken.